# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' using add edge from networkx

Tags: python, tuples, typeerror, networkx

```py
for m in match:
    print("type of m", type(m))
    G.add_edge((rec.seq, rec.id), m)
```

We are trying to add an edge to the graph, match is a list of tuples, and `(rec.seq, rec.id)` is an exist node in G from tuple type, but we still keep having `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: Could you provide an example for `req` and `m`?

Comment: this is (rec.seq, rec.id)
 ('CTAGATCGCATTGTGAGCCAGTCAGCCAGAGAGCAA', 'E00576:54:H3325CCXY:8:1101:18274:1538')
and this is m
('CAAATGCCACACAAAACAGCAAAAATGTGAAAAATG' ,['E00576:54:H3325CCXY:8:1101:17066:1309'])

Answer (score 1):

Nodes are stored as key of a dictionary, so the node must be of a hashable type.

```
>>> g.add_edge((1,2),[3,4])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The solution consists in either converting it to tuple or to pick the string you want as node from the list of matches, according to your use case.

Example:

```
for m in match:
    G.add_edge((rec.seq, rec.id), (m[0], m[1][0]))
```